# Should I include Sphinx and/or Nose in my module's requirements.txt?

Tags: python, standards, pip, setup.py, requirements.txt

I've created a Python module on Github that uses Nose for unit testing and Sphinx for generating documentation. I have two questions:

- Should I include Sphinx and/or Nose in my module's dependencies in setup.py (install_requires), as they are not required for basic module functionality, only if you want to build the documentation/run tests yourself?
- Should I include Sphinx and/or Nose in my module's requirements.txt on Github, for the same reasons but users that download my project from Github might be more likely to build docs/run tests?

This is my first Python module, so a bit of best practices/standards advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `nose` and/or `sphinx` are not required for the basic functionality of your package then don't include them in `setup.py`. There's no point in forcing users to install packages that they might not ever use. If they eventually want to help you develop your package they can install the requisite packages themselves.

`requirements.txt` files should also not include development-required packages, though there's some wiggle room there.

For example, over at [`pandas`](http://www.github.com/pydata/pandas) we use requirements files for our Travis-CI builds. You can check them out [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/ci).

One thing we are considering is building our documentation on Travis-CI, as sometimes a failed doc build catches bugs that the test suite doesn't. In that case we *would* put `sphinx` in the requirements file of the Python version we use to build the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include those nice-to-haves in your setup.py. You can write a requirements file for developers if you like; users won't need one. For example, call one file `reqs.development`:

```
-e . # include the package defined by setup.py in editable (development) mode
nose
sphinx
```

Users can `pip install yourmodule` or `pip install https://your/tarball`, developers can fork, clone and `pip install -r reqs.development`.